# FadeOut JQuery Functionnot working per object

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I was wondering if it is possible to do this. I need to create  jquery function which fades out any object that is clicked on. I though this would work but it doesnt, this fades out all objects when one is clicked on, is there a way to do this or would i need to create a seperate function for each fadeout id or class?

```
$("*").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Because `*` means *all* items and that includes the body and clicks propagate, so your body tag is fading out

Comment: You might like to be more specific with your selector, eg `$("div.content>*")` or you could add [`stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("*").click(function(e) {
  $(e.target).fadeOut( "slow" );
});
```

You have to recieve the element clicked on, so put one argument in the function, and call it "e" for element, or what you'd like to call it. Then use e.target to get the div that was clicked on. And then add `.fadeOut("slow")`, for the element to fade out slow

But notice. This is on ALL elements in the body. Replace "*", with the id of the div (example: "#id") you want this to happen in.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for. Im doing a web development bootcamp so im pretty new to it still. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! I could recommend to print out e (console.log(e)), so you can see all the things you can access with the element you get :) It could help you out in the nearest future. Good luck with the bootcamp!